# How can I make backspace work in visual block mode?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, visual-block

I hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>Shift-i</kbd><kbd>x</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>, and `x` is correctly inserted on the current line and in the 3 lines below it in the same column. Good.

I hit <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>Shift-i</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd> a character is deleted only on the current line.

How can I make it delete characters on the visual block-selected lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help blockwise-operators`:

> ```
> Visual-block Insert  
> (...) Works only for adding text to a line, not for deletions.
> ```

An alternative is to select the column to the left and use `x` or `d`, i.e., <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>3</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>d</kbd>.

Comment: Technically d works too, and that’s easier for my fingers