# Understanding interaction between visual, autoindent, and paste option

Tags: indentation, visual-block, paste, autoindent

Let's start form this faulty C++ source file

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{
            1,2},
            9,3},
            4,2}
    };
}
```

which is a legit transitory state if you've just copied those 6 numbers from a space-separated text file with two columns.

The last step is to add opening braces on the three lines, so you might put the cursor on the `1`, and then go <kbd>Ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>{</kbd><kbd>Escape</kbd>. Doing so, however, you end up with this,

```
#include <vector>
int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v{
        {1,2}
            1,1}
            1,2}
    };
}
```

because the auto indentation pulled the line where the cursor initially is to the left (for whatever reason will be explained in [this previous question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/27982/understanding-indenting-rules-for-c-files)), i.e. [it deleted text, thus breaking out of the block visual mode](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/27890/6498).

However, if that key sequence is used after `:set paste`, then the edit is as desired.

I'd like to know how these things play together.

Comment: Doesn't `:h 'paste'` answer much of this? It lists all the settings that disabled/reset.

Comment: Yes, I think it does, but I'm still figuring out which ones affect the behavior. It's not `smartindent`, nor `autoindent`. I'll post a self answer if I don't get one, but I wouldn't delete this question, since it's taking more than just a look at the help.

Comment: It takes a lot more than that for a question to be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the reason why `:set paste` solves the issue is that, among other things, it deactivates `cindent`, and `cindent` makes use of `cinkeys`'s default value, which triggers the reindentation if one types `{` (or other characters) at the beginning of the line.